# Multiple screen size support android mobile application

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout, responsive

Currently I am developing a android mobile app using android studio (java). Since it should multiple screen size I make another layout file with respect to the screen size which i need(xxx-high density). But still it is not supporting. The buttons are moving out of the screen.

I have used Relative Layout as a parent layout for all of my activity.

please somebody help me to get out of this trouble.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ1I6.png)

Comment: Use constraint layout and set the constraints accordingly. It will ease your work.

Comment: instead of giving(xxxhd).,you can specify the screenSize. It will work fine. you dont have to modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as the folowing,

**res -> layout -> New -> Layout Resource File**

[image]

Dont forget to give the same file name, just specify the size.